# C++ ambiguous template overloads

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to use template specialization to return different types based on the value of the template variable.

I've moved from trying to branch at runtime rather than compile time using `typeof()`, unspecialized templates and using `std::enable_if_t<>`. I think this may stem from a lack of understanding about how the template functions are resolving.

```
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    T request()
    {
        T ret = getVal<T>();
        return ret;
    }

private:
    float foo = 2.f;
    int bar = 1;

    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, float>::value, bool>::type
    getVal() { return foo; }

    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value, bool>::type
    getVal() { return bar; }

    template<typename T>
    T getVal()
    {
        std::cout << "T is type " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        throw std::bad_typeid();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    int i;
    float f;
    i = t.template request<int>();
    f = t.template request<float>();
}
```

I'm expecting this to resolve to three different functions, but I'm not sure if it is:

```
T Test::getVal()

int Test::getVal()

float Test::getVal()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use ordinary template specialization? Something like the following might work: `template<typename T> T getVal(){ /* default impl */ } ... template<> int getVal<int>(){ return bar; } ... template<> float getVal<float>(){ return foo; }`

Comment: One of the problems you will run in to here is that `getVal<int>` will match both the second and third declaration of `getVal` and will be ambigous. What exactly is your end goal here? If the question spawns from nothing but curiosity this is quite unusual way of using templates and better examples could be helpful for better understanding.

Comment: I don't think that question quite answers the same question, as `GC::Allocate<A>` was resolving successfully in that instance, whereas `Test::request<int>()` isn't resolving here. The solution of passing an additional param to the function isn't helpful in this case, as the goal is to get a value from Test in another class's initilizer list. Although that's out of the scope of the example

Comment: To just fix the ambigous problem you need to change the last version to only work for types that are not `int` or `float`. `typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, int>::value && !std::is_same<T, float>::value, bool>::type getVal` for example.

Comment: "Although that's out of the scope of the example" not it isnt really. What you want to achieve by this code is completely relevant, only when you tell us what you want to achieve we can tell you how to achieve it, just fixing compiler errors never leads to clean code

Comment: I think I did oversimplify, in reality I'm trying to use `getVal()` to get the back of a specific array in the class, like this: `std::vector<T> vec = getVal<T>();`

Comment: @Mokou, "get the back of a specific array" (one element?) but return a vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily by specializing `getVal()`, though you may have oversimplified the question

```
class Test {
public:
    template <typename T>
    T request() {
        T ret = getVal<T>();
        return ret;
    }

private:
    float foo = 2.f;
    int bar = 1;

    template<typename T>
    T getVal() {
        std::cout << "T is type " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        throw std::bad_typeid();
    }
};

// add specializations
template<>
float Test::getVal<float>() { return foo; }

template <>
int Test::getVal<int>() { return bar; }

int main() {
    Test t;
    int i = t.request<int>(); // don't need template keyword here
    float f = t.request<float>();
}
```

If you're able to use c++17, it is even simpler with `if constexpr` and a single `getVal`

```
template<typename T>
auto getVal() {
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, T>) {
    return foo;
  } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<float, T>) {
    return bar;
  } else {
    std::cout << "T is type " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    throw std::bad_typeid();
  }
}
```

Comment: Care that specialization should always be visible before usage (ODR).

Comment: Using the C++17 solution ended up working flawlessly

Comment: Probably better to replace `throw` by `static_assert(always_false<T>, "!")` to have compile time error instead of runtime one.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `template<typename T> T getVal()` make call ambiguous when the SFINAEd one succeed.

One solution is to restrict that one with complement condition...

But tag dispatching is an easy alternative way to fix your issue:

```
template <typename> struct Tag{};

class Test
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    T request() const
    {
        return getVal(Tag<T>{});
    }

private:
    float foo = 2.f;
    int bar = 1;

    float getVal(Tag<float>) const { return foo; }
    int getVal(Tag<int>) const { return bar; }

    template<typename T> void getVal(Tag<T>) = delete;
};
```